# How to conditionally extend class with methods/properties in Typescript OOP

Tags: typescript, oop

I have dozens of forms with different fields - checkboxes, uploads, inputs.

Let`s say I need class for handling the form - the problem is that one class needs inputForm, uploadForm.
Other form needs only checkboxForm. How to handle it in OOP way?
I came up with configure parameter the problem is that auto-completion works so I can access non-initialized fields.
Ideally I do not want them visible (in auto-completion as a client of the class).
I am aware of decorator pattern but looks like I would end-up with a messy solution with couple of wrappers.

```
class InputForm {
    // Define InputForm class here
}

class UploadForm {
    // Define UploadForm class here
}

class CheckboxForm {
    // Define CheckboxForm class here
}

interface Config {
    includeInputForm: boolean;
    includeUploadForm: boolean;
    includeCheckboxForm: boolean;
}

class MultiForm {
    inputForm?: InputForm;
    uploadForm?: UploadForm;
    checkboxForm?: CheckboxForm;


    constructor(private config: Config) {
        if (this.config.includeInputForm) {
            this.inputForm = new InputForm();
        }
        if (this.config.includeUploadForm) {
            this.uploadForm = new UploadForm();
        }
        if (this.config.includeCheckboxForm) {
            this.checkboxForm = new CheckboxForm();
        }
    }
}


const config: Config = {
    includeInputForm: true,
    includeUploadForm: false,
    includeCheckboxForm: true
};

const multiForm = new MultiForm(config);
```

Comment: Class declarations must have statically known keys. You can describe such a type with conditionally-included keys, but you need a type assertion to say that `MultiForm` is a constructor of that. It might look as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mxEMxW). This might be "oop" but it fights against the way TypeScript does things.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes it address question perfectly. Looks very complex though :)

Comment: You might consider a completely different approach to this; why not just pass in the properties you care about directly like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQjGJN)? I mean, maybe that's not the exact approach you want, but it's at least more composable.  I'll write up an answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript, a [`class` declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) must have *statically known* members (class instances are implemented as [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces), and interfaces must have statically known members).  So it is impossible for you to have code like

```
class MultiForm {
  ⋮
}
const mf1 = new MultiForm(config1);
const mf2 = new MultiForm(config2);
```

where `mf1` and `mf2` have different known keys. Either both have an `inputForm` property or neither do.

So the simple answer to the question as asked is "no, you can't do this".

---

However, you could *describe* the type of a class constructor that behaves this way, meaning you can write a regular class declaration and then [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that a variable holding a reference to that class is of the desired type.  So it would look like

```
class _MultiForm {
  ⋮
}
type MultiForm<T extends Config> = ⋯;
const MultiForm = _MultiForm as 
  new <T extends Config>(config: T) => MultiForm<T>;
const mf1 = new MultiForm(config1);
const mf2 = new MultiForm(config2);
```

Here we have a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `MultiForm<T>` [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) which should have or lack keys depending on the particular subtype of `Config` passed in as the `T` type argument.  And then `mf1` and `mf2` could have different keys.

That might suffice for some use cases, although it would need lots of testing; anything that requires classes to have statically known keys will break, so even if the above works, the following won't:

```
class Oops<T extends Config> extends MultiForm<T> { } // error!
// --------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~
// Base constructor return type 'MultiForm<T>' is not an 
// object type or intersection of object types with 
// statically known members.
```

But let's press on, assuming it's okay.

---

I will assume we will leave your class declaration unchanged except for renaming it out of the way:

```
class _MultiForm {
    inputForm?: InputForm;
    uploadForm?: UploadForm;
    checkboxForm?: CheckboxForm;

    constructor(private config: Config) {
        if (this.config.includeInputForm) {
            this.inputForm = new InputForm();
        }
        if (this.config.includeUploadForm) {
            this.uploadForm = new UploadForm();
        }
        if (this.config.includeCheckboxForm) {
            this.checkboxForm = new CheckboxForm();
        }
    }
}
```

Now we have to determine how to write the `_MultiForm` class and the `MultiForm<T>` type alias, and it's probably going to be somewhat ugly no matter what, since we have to translate something like `{includeUploadForm: true, includeInputForm: false, includeCheckboxForm: true}` to be "just like `_MultiForm` except that the `uploadForm` and `checkboxForm` properties are *required*, and the `inputForm` property is *omitted*.  We can use the [`Required`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) and the [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) utility types, but it will still be ugly.

First let's define a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the keys of `MultiForm` we want to keep/omit:

```
type FormKeys = "inputForm" | "uploadForm" | "checkboxForm";
```

And for any of these there will be a corresponding `includeXxx` version, which we can use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) to generate:

```
type IncludeForm<K extends string> = `include${Capitalize<K>}`
```

This lets us redefine `Config` in terms of those, although it's not necessary:

```
type Config = { [P in IncludeForm<FormKeys>]: boolean }
```

Then, for a given subtype `T` of `Config`, let's compute `PresentProps<T>`, the subset of `FormKeys` we want to have present and required:

```
type PresentProps<T extends Config> = {
    [K in FormKeys]: T[IncludeForm<K>] extends true ? K : never
}[FormKeys]
```

That's a *distributive object type* (as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) where we use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it to get the union of its contents. That means we're getting the union of `T[IncludeForm<K>] extends true ? K : never` for all `K` in `FormKeys`.  Meaning we're getting all form keys `K` where the property of `T` at key `IncludeForm<K>` is `true`.

Then `MultiForm` is finally:

```
type MultiForm<T extends Config> =
    Omit<_MultiForm, FormKeys> &
    Required<Pick<_MultiForm, PresentProps<T>>>
```

where we omit all the form keys from `_MultiForm` first, and then add back in all those which are present as `true` in `T` as required.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const config = {
    includeInputForm: true,
    includeUploadForm: false,
    includeCheckboxForm: true
} as const;

const multiForm = new MultiForm(config);
multiForm.checkboxForm
//        ^? (property) checkboxForm: CheckboxForm
multiForm.inputForm
//        ^? (property) inputForm: InputForm
multiForm.uploadForm; // error!
// -----> ~~~~~~~~~~
// Property 'uploadForm' does not exist on type
```

Now, that works as you desired. Except note that I didn't write `const config: Config =`  the way you did. If you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `config` as the `Config` type, you're throwing away any more specific information the compiler has about the type. If you want the compiler to know that `includeInputForm` is of type `true` and not `boolean`, you can't annotate. Additionally you need something like a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to keep track of the literal `true` and `false`, because those tend to be widened to `boolean` also.

One more test:

```
const mf2 = new MultiForm({
    includeUploadForm: true,
    includeCheckboxForm: false,
    includeInputForm: false
});
mf2.uploadForm // okay
mf2.inputForm // error
```

Also looks good. Note that by declaring the config inline as an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) we can avoid the whole need for `as const`.

---

So, it works. Is it worth it? I'd say it probably isn't. It fights against the TypeScript type system. It has to circumvent normal class declarations, and then it also has to jump through type hoops.  Instead of having `includeXXX`, why not just initialize the class with a single `forms` property that is some subtype of `{inputForm?: InputForm, checkboxForm?: CheckboxForm, uploadForm?: UploadForm}` and make the class generic? Yes, you'd be required to write `multiForm.forms.inputForm` instead of `multiForm.inputForm`, but now a `MultiForm<T>` would always have a `forms` property, so the keys of `MultiForm` are known. And you don't have to jump through hoops translating `includeXXX` to other stuff, you'd just initialize the properties yourself. Or maybe that wouldn't work, and is technically out scope for the question as asked anyway. But you should probably be sure your use case actually requires such a byzantine solution before going with it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECSB2AHArgFwGIHsBOBbaA3gFDSnQD050AIgKYBmAlvLXEmlntKJDABa1stIgF8iRHlGgBVRCExgAJp3zEyFKnSYsZchcpz5J-QcLETwUgMIDgAawBGmAB4rCJMpRoNmrG7XsnV0NuSxMhUXELXmgAfQBZZBBURjc1MmYUDEMAfgAuNiyVAG4PUmQ9JRV83Xkqw1L1YFtHF2qC-0C2hvEmzHgIVGxkYFQcAApEbEYANzBUVmB+pgBzDuXGFYBKd3V1RnpocdQ+RggAOiX4VfPmUGRFWgQiwx30vb2Ts9v2bK4AXmgLAA7oUOIZxltGh9oGIYdADkcvhcrjc7iAHrRZHUDHg3mV4dBkecKji3ICQbV9CpIdCPnCYYjjqcURsVj97o9Oq1gnjdoTSMTmgEeeSgbRQdygjSoQT1AzSGJzKgAJ6IVgqADStBVMEBACJMuC8ProAAfaD60nUwymi364VdXm4fWlIiq9VsTm0FQAHk10FozgW8EUMEG03gKwAfNBAQADdGYgAkBCsYEQjFQYBAjAAXrR-dGRPHxB6-Gy44RoABtAAKCPgXoxjz9Wp1EGjAF0Ck5MCBaGAm8q1aw60IILR4Khx5hEBBfQAVQPBqdh6BWNmxwHvWsB5jQdu6nvQRc1hDev2a7srkProbIVg5aABgosGaCUQ1o8QLtl0fQIkySpIYS63muMCbtcmzbgSADyuBZr6CRJCkKgADSHoY2q6rGABkBIAEq0AAjsgjBCIovp1ow9jIUBaGGJh460JO06zvOS7Rtx4hXIMgGoSBAJxAxQn4JABKUmBQZ3pBW7jKimwFIuOz-LGol+ou0ZusY0BwXOC7LjJEEblu4GhjAGmgVp1YiBogbYNgOAAIREF4AC0nled5Pm+X53mxgAfsFIUhW5VAAEKQIs-QRiMYzYNAQioMg2BNuW0AAORWXgXGZQiMDwJgqDQEO0DhdAmAOAAVgEJUZTgjYLNgk6jIw-SVYcVW1aMRKjjAwJZnw5VeIM8y0TmIAqtAdhFcCTa4LQuAOIIFxRHxJWKSsVa7kmjzPMauAFA+tDoQSe1YpUuJHdA9A5pOZ37PA3pSt0eDHcMZilTAG06bFJW4IJYqUjluAKWysqA8BKiXC00qGBVMIAHrPpMTnqtgqo7I6oqGB0cNvbgRBQ4xeA-C8eCIx8KNHFMc6CFjjYUzdB1-ETJNiSSV0lPZghOdgrkeQF0ChaLgUVRxDPTZl1r1Hg+WKJgrFAsVK5nCVHUZbx-3QLg9AAExViDQMQrtz0tpdZJ40Sn2PRk5uYq9zoFHdIAPedDv7b8Kgu-dZiQwbXNW1wXiYHYYAqsTgdGmzvOOTgQA)